# Remove circle after clicking on input type submit (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting a border and a circle after clicking on a input type submit in Bootstrap:

[image]

I managed to remove the border by adding this to css:

```
*:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

However, I can't get rid of the circle. 
Would be delighted if someone could help me.

Thanks,

R.G.

Comment: Could you show the html and css code for this particular issue please

Comment: Remove "disabled" from the class

Answer (score 0):

It's probably disabled. Check the submit button tag to see if `disabled` is an attribute.